# How do I remove the display that shows up when I change desktops in Windows?

Tags: windows-11, desktop

I am on Windows 11, and ever since my laptop forcefully updated itself, whenever I change desktops, there is a display at the bottom of my screen that shows the name of the desktop I am currently on that appears for a few seconds, which I find sometimes blocks things I'm trying to look at or click on.

I tried to look through the settings and search it up, but couldn't find anything. If anyone knows how to get rid of it, any help is appreciated. [image: Image of desktop pop up]

Comment: Windows supports multiple desktops, but I'm not familiar with it placing such an indicator permanently on the desktop indicating which one is active. I suggest looking at Multitasking Settings, or updating your video driver in case that indicator is some artifact of that.